# Cannot find type 'NSSound' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, nssound

In this tutorial: https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part4/

I'm trying to run the metronome, about 1/2 way down the page.  It's a simple call to NSSound and I get an error cannot find the type.  I change that type to "Any" and then it doesn't find NSSound. I think it should be apart of UIKit, but it doesn't seem to be working.

***Q. How can I run NSSound() in an iOS, SwiftUI app?***

Other imports don't resolve the error:

```
import UIKit
import AudioUnit
import AVFAudio
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import AudioUnit
import CoreAudio
import Foundation



let bellSound: NSSound? = {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "bell", withExtension: "mp3") else { return nil }
    return NSSound(contentsOf: url, byReference: true)
}()
```

Comment: ```NSSound``` is only available in macOS. not in iOS. Are u using macOS for the development?

Comment: The target is iOS, that explains it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSSound` is only available in `macOS` environment(actually `macOS 10 +` . Not in `iOS` environment. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssound) for further details.